# PHP - Multidimensional Associative Array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

this is my first time posting here. I learning PHP and ran into a problem. I tried many times to solve it but i can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. This is the array that I have. Now I need to call each product in it

```
$productItems = array(

            "hardware"  => array(


                        "hardware1" => array(

                                        "title" => "Graphics Card",
                                        "price" => 11,
                                        "blurb" => "Hardware Ipsum",
                                        "img1"      => "IMG9",
                                    ),

                            "hardware2" => array(

                                        "title" => "Graphics Card",
                                        "price" => 11,
                                        "blurb" => "Hardware Ipsum",
                                        "img1"      => "IMG9",
                                    ),

                            "hardware3" => array(

                                        "title" => "Graphics Card",
                                        "price" => 11,
                                        "blurb" => "Hardware Ipsum",
                                        "img1"      => "IMG9",
                                    ),

                            ),

                "software"  => array(


                            "software1" => array(

                                        "title" => "Office",
                                        "price" => 11,
                                        "blurb" => "Software Ipsum",
                                        "img1"      => "IMG9",
                                    ),

                            "software2" => array(

                                        "title" => "Office",
                                        "price" => 11,
                                        "blurb" => "Software Ipsum",
                                        "img1"      => "IMG9",
                                    ),

                            "software3" => array(

                                        "title" => "Office",
                                        "price" => 11,
                                        "blurb" => "Software Ipsum",
                                        "img1"      => "IMG9",
                                    ),

                            ),

                "peripherals"   => array(


                            "peripheral1"   => array(

                                        "title" => "Gaming Mice",
                                        "price" => 11,
                                        "blurb" => "Peripheral Ipsum",
                                        "img1"      => "IMG9",
                                    ),

                            "peripheral2"   => array(

                                        "title" => "Gaming Mice",
                                        "price" => 11,
                                        "blurb" => "Peripheral Ipsum",
                                        "img1"      => "IMG9",
                                    ),

                            "peripheral3"   => array(

                                        "title" => "Gaming Mice",
                                        "price" => 11,
                                        "blurb" => "Peripheral Ipsum",
                                        "img1"      => "IMG9",
                                    ),
                            ),
        );
```

This is what I used to call the whole list in the menu.php page. Up to here everything works. the problem is in the following code.

```
<?php 

    foreach ($productItems as $products => $items) {
        echo ucwords($products).'<p style="margin-bottom: 0px;">&nbsp;</p>'; 
            foreach ($items as $product => $item) { ?>
                <li><a href="product.php?item=<?php echo $item; ?>" style = "text-align: center">
                <?php echo $item["title"]; ?></a> <sup>€</sup><?php echo $item["price"].'<br><br />';?></li>
            <?php   }} ?>"
```

and to list the details of each product i used this code but i'm having errors saying its not defined

```
if (isset($_GET['items'])) {

    $productItem = strip_bad_chars($_GET['items']);

    $products = $productItems[$productItem];

}

if (isset($_GET['item'])) {

    $menuItem = strip_bad_chars($_GET['item']);

    $product = $products[$menuItem];

}
```

```
    <h1><img src="img1/<?php echo $product["img1"]; ?>.jpg" alt="<?php echo $product["title"];?>"> <br>
    <?php echo $product["title"]; ?> <span class="price"><sup>€</sup><?php echo $product["price"]; ?></span></h1>
    <p><?php echo $product["blurb"]; ?></p>


    <br>


</div><!--product-->
```

can anyone understand what am i doing wrong? Thank you.

Comment: Can you show what is your desired out you want?

Comment: i made a mistake. the problem starts at 'if (isset($_GET['items'])) {'

Comment: What are you using for `$_GET['items']` and `$_GET['item']`?  Whats the full error message?  What debugging have you done?

Comment: this is what is supposed to look like. where there are hardware software and peripherals the titles with no link. only products with link that send to another page with full product description.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/64831912/Screenshot%202015-05-12%2019.44.40.png

Comment: initially i only used one $_GET['item'] which was used from foreach ($items as $product => $item). what i'm getting is an undefined variable product

Comment: The function `strip_bad_chars` is not a core function, it needs to be defined somewhere. What do you expect this to do?

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

It could be a problem introduced by `strip_bad_chars()`.  Where id that come from?

This is likely an unnecessary function depending on the source of the submitted variable.

---

### This works!

I ran the following test:

```
$productItems = array("hardware"  => array(
  "hardware1" => array("title" => "Graphics Card","price" => 11,"blurb" => "Hardware Ipsum","img1"      => "IMG9",  ),
  "hardware2" => array("title" => "Graphics Card","price" => 11,"blurb" => "Hardware Ipsum","img1"      => "IMG9",  ),
  "hardware3" => array("title" => "Graphics Card","price" => 11,"blurb" => "Hardware Ipsum","img1"      => "IMG9",   )),
  "software"  => array("software1" => array(
  "title" => "Office","price" => 11,"blurb" => "Software Ipsum","img1"      => "IMG9",),
  "software2" => array("title" => "Office","price" => 11,"blurb" => "Software Ipsum","img1"      => "IMG9",  ),
  "software3" => array("title" => "Office","price" => 11,"blurb" => "Software Ipsum","img1"      => "IMG9",),  ),
  "peripherals" => array("peripheral1"   => array("title" => "Gaming Mice","price" => 11,"blurb" => "Peripheral Ipsum","img1"      => "IMG9",   ),
  "peripheral2" => array("title" => "Gaming Mice","price" => 11,"blurb" => "Peripheral Ipsum","img1"      => "IMG9",  ),
  "peripheral3" => array("title" => "Gaming Mice","price" => 11,"blurb" => "Peripheral Ipsum","img1"      => "IMG9",   )));


$products = $productItems['hardware'];
$product = $products['hardware1'];
echo $product["img1"] . "\n" . $product["title"] . "\n" . $product["title"]. "\n" . $product["price"]. "\n" .$product["blurb"];
```

### Result:

IMG9
Graphics Card
Graphics Card
11

---

**Now copy above code and run it.**

**Then add strip_bad_chars() And run again.**

```
$products = $productItems[strip_bad_chars('hardware')];
$product = $products[strip_bad_chars('hardware1')];

echo $product["img1"] . "\n" . $product["title"] . "\n" . $product["title"]. "\n" . $product["price"]. "\n" .$product["blurb"];
```

Comment: I highly suspect `strip_bad_chars()`  Have you tried it without  `strip_bad_chars()` ?

Comment: sorry everyone. i tried everything that was suggested but still not working.

What i'm getting is this  Notice: Undefined variable: item on line 47, 48, 48 and another on line 49 in the products.php page

lines 47, 48, 49 are the last bit of code i pasted which starts <h1><img src="img1/<?php echo $product["img1"];

Comment: Sorry?  Get this done.  It's been two hours already.  Try again.  I revised my answer.

Comment: i thank you for your help but in case you got the wrong idea i've been on it for 2 days before posting here. and in case i did not mention it, i'm still a beginner in php so if its easy for you for me it is not so sorry for taking more than 2 hours and as i said thank you for your help and your time

Comment: I'M NOT DONE HERE.  DO YOU NOT WANT TO FINISH IT????????  Do what I suggested and get back to me with an answer.  This would take me two minutes to fix if it were on my system.  Guaranteed!  This is simple stuff.  There is nothing here that could not be solved in minutes!!!!  Let's get this DONE!  I made it very easy, copy and paste my code into your PHP editor.  Copy mine, do NOT use your code!

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a conceptual error:

You're checking if $_GET['items'] exists, but you never pass a value to it.

In the part of code where you create the link, you need to pass the items id too

```
<a href="product.php?item=<?php echo $item; ?>&items=<?=$products?>"
```

A thing that you could improve, is the logic check part:

```
if (isset($_GET['item'])) {
    $menuItem = strip_bad_chars($_GET['item']);
    $product = $products[$menuItem];
}
```

this part of code could be executed only if $_GET['items'] isset

So the code in that part, should be something like this:

```
$product = null;
if (isset($_GET['items'] && isset($_GET['item'])) {
    $productItem = strip_bad_chars($_GET['items']);
    $menuItem = strip_bad_chars($_GET['item']);
    $product = $productItems[$productItem][$menuItem];
}
```

Comment: first of all. is the array good? could it be done in another way?

Answer (score 0):

First check what are you sending in `$_GET['items']` then check what are you storing after cleanse `strip_bad_chars($_GET['items']);`

Alternately print in every cycle of your foreach's to see what you really stored in your array.

---

EDIT:

this $_GET is wrong

```
if (isset($_GET['items'])) {

$productItem = strip_bad_chars($_GET['items']);

$products = $productItems[$productItem];
```

}

you are calling "items" when you defined "item" without "s"